# Holes in leaves and black specks on lower leaves

Tags: diseases, pests, fungus, bugs, zinnia

I tried adding pictures but it isn't working. I have young zinnia plants that I started from seed about two months ago. They're just barely coming up on the point where they'll flower but suddenly I discovered a leaf with a gigantic hole. I freaked out, thinking it was a caterpillar! It should be noted this is my first little garden so I have basically no idea what could be happening! I contacted a friend who had me make an oil/soap/water mixture to spray on the plants. I wasn't able to ever find a caterpillar and am now convinced that's not the problem.

It has been about a week and all of the leaves on my poor baby plants are filled with holes. It seems to start as the leaf weakening and thinning out, then the holes develop where the thin portion was. Now just today I noticed some small black specs about the size of finely ground pepper on the lower leaves of the plants. So after some googling I thought it could either be some sort of fungus or maybe a very tiny pest? Does anyone have any ideas? I so badly want them to flower! Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Black specks could be droppings of whatever pest is eating your leaves. Sorry if that raises the "ick" factor.  More likely fungus, though, I'd guess.

Comment: Welcome Kindra! Sometimes you need a certain amount of rep to add your pictures, but you're all set now, so try again. In case you need the method, press the grey "edit" word on your question, it will open. Then click on the icon in the top row that looks like a mountain, and you'll get options to add pictures either from your computer or a web address. If you still have trouble, please leave us a note. Someone will help you, so we can see your little plants!